# How to return a list on different lines in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Right now, my codes output is ['I love mac and cheese', ' cheese', 'se'], how would I change it so that the output would be a string and appear on different lines so
"I love mac and cheese (first line)
cheese (second line)
se (third line)
. This is the output when the user inputs .369 for fraction and I love mac and cheese for sentence

```
def echo(a,b, count):
    newlen = int(len(b)*a)
    if newlen > 0:
        count+=1
        return [b] + echo(a,b[-newlen:], count)
    else:
        count+=1
        print("Number of echos: ", count)
        return [b]
        
def main():
    count=0
    f=float(input("Enter the fraction"))
    sentence=input("Enter the sentence")
    print(echo(f,sentence, count))


main()
```

Comment: Do you need to `print` the results of echo directly?  Or can you store it and manipulate it?  Storing and manipulating is simple, like im_baby suggests.  however, if the last recursion "needs to know" and join the strings back, that's a bit harder.  Also, 2 suggestions:  first change your testing code to ` f= .369 # float(input("Enter the fraction"))`
 and ` sentence="I love mac and cheese" #input("Enter the sentence")`.  Second, change your `a` variable to `frac` and use `breakpoint()` to look at what's going on.  `a` hides the pdb `a` command which prints out all parameter values.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method with new-line.

```
>>> a = ['some text', 'some other text', 'some more']
>>> print(a)
['some text', 'some other text', 'some more']
>>> print('\n'.join(a))
some text
some other text
some more
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Assuming you have successfully achieved the right sentence...

```
sentence = ["I love mac and cheese", "cheese", "se"]
for item in sentence:
    print(item)
    # If you want a newline character between each item:
    # print("\n") \n is the python syntax for a newline
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign the return of your `echo` function to a list, then iterate over that list printing the elements.

```py
def main():
    count = 0
    f = float(input("Enter the fraction"))
    sentence = input("Enter the sentence")
    results = echo(f, sentence, count)
    for line in results:
        print(line)
```

Results in:

```sh
Enter the fraction.369
Enter the sentenceI love mac and cheese
Number of echos:  3
I love mac and cheese
 cheese
se
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the list returned by the echo method in a variable and use a for loop to print out the contents separately.

```
results=echo(f,sentence, count)

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I think.

So, the key is to is to understand when you are returning back to the outside world, i.e. to print.  The item to watch is `count`, because it's at 1 right before that.

```
def echo(frac,b, count):
    newlen = int(len(b)*frac)
    if newlen > 0:
        count+=1
        #`count` is going to go up for the inner, recursive, calls
        res = [b] + echo(frac,b[-newlen:], count)

        if count == 1:
            #back to the caller.
            return "\n".join(res)
        else:
            #nope, this a recursive call, leave as list of strings.
            return res
    else:
        count+=1
        print("Number of echos: ", count)
        if count == 1:
            return b
        else:
            return [b]

        
def main():
    count=0
    f= .369 # float(input("Enter the fraction"))
    sentence="I love mac and cheese" #input("Enter the sentence")
    print(echo(f,sentence, count))


main()
```

#### output:

```
Number of echos:  3
I love mac and cheese
 cheese
se
```

In a way, it helps if instead of `count` you think of as is as `level` or `depth` and understand that it tracks how deep in the recursions you are.  Nice question - I always struggle with recursion exits and this is a nice trick to know, tracking levels.

Also, if you had a short sentence or a very small fraction, you might not hit newlen > 0 even once.  Your code should allow for that in your else branch and return the `"\n".join([b])`.

without having to recurse because of small fraction:

```
    f= .01 # float(input("Enter the fraction"))
    sentence="I love mac and cheese" #input("Enter the sentence")
```

#### output:

```
Number of echos:  1
I love mac and cheese
```